# Real time zooming in video player

Tags: video, media-player, zoom

Is there any video players out there that can zoom in the video in real time?

Comment: For which operating system are you wanting this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use VLC (cross platform) you can enable "Magnification/Zoom". To do this from the window menu select Tools>Effects and Filters. In the Effects and Filters window find the Video Effects tab (in the highest row of tabs) then locate the Geometry tab (in the second row of tabs). There you will find the Magnification/Zoom check box. This will overlay a thumbnail of the video and a zoom factor slider which you can use to zoom around the video as it plays.

Hope this does it for you :)